# throw .net-wrappable exception from native COM-Dll

Tags: exception, com, com-interop, seh

In a native-C++-Dll (MFC): how to throw an Exception (with some additional text) that can be catched and handled from a .NET-Client?

This is the native-MFC-Dll which wants to throw an Exception:

```
void RGaugeTVDDataReader::LoadDataFromFile_HandleException(const CString& szPath) const
{
    CString sMessage;
    sMessage.Format(_T("TVD-File %s"), static_cast<LPCTSTR>(szPath));

    /*1*/ AfxThrowFileException(CFileException::genericException, -1, static_cast<LPCTSTR>(sMessage));
    /*2*/ throw std::runtime_error(CT2A(sMessage));
}
```

The Caller is a .Net-Dll which uses the native dll via a .net-generated-COM-Wrapper.
Both variants (/*1*/ and /*2*/) fall into the catch-Block of the .Net-Component but what I get here is just a ´System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException´ and the exceptionmessage says "External component has thrown an exception.". Included `ErrorCode` and `HResult` is 0x80004005. There is no inner exception, nothing to find about my given text and the stacktrace only contains the managed part.

So the question is: how to throw an excpetion from the native-c++-dll so that a .net-client using it via COM can at least see the message-string?

Alternative question: how to catch and handle the thrown exception in .net correctly?

regards

Comment: Notice that C++ exceptions are a native feature of the C++ language and must never ever cross language boundaries in the call stack, not even from C++ to C. Don’t confuse them with SEH exceptions. Are you familiar with COM exception handling? Look up failure HRESULTs, IErrorInfo, ISupportErrorInfo; it’s not hard but it takes a non trivial amount of work. For certain standard HRESULTs the RCW will translate to equivalent .NET standard exceptions; for others you will be catching a .NET COMException.

Comment: Never, never, never allow a C++ exception to escape from your C++ code due to a COM call. You should only return HRESULT error codes. Try looking up the documentation around the API SetErrorInfo() which is part of the COM documentation. Specifically, see this link which has an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-seterrorinfo